# Insert a new branch between two existing branches

Tags: tfs, branch

I currently have two branches, Parent(Main) and Child(Release).  I need to inject a new branch between Parent and Child, making it Parent(Main), Child(Intermediate), and Grandchild(Release).  I know I can accomplish this through the following steps:

1. Rename Release to Intermediate
2. Create a new branch from Intermediate and call it Release

Unfortunately, the branch rename process has done unexpected things in the past with change history.  Is there any alternative?

Comment: The steps you have listed are exactly how I would do this. What "unexpected" things did you see in the past when you renamed a branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming is the proper way to go here and you are correct that renaming the root of a branch can cause problems in future merges.  There is a good article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandrur/archive/2010/06/09/renaming-branches-in-tfs-2010.aspx) that describes the potential problems and how to work around them.